Fluid not pushing water out of the way
I am trying to fill a container with fluid from the bottom in a pumping animation, but it's not pushing fluid through liquid after the first pump.
Blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sh_xLfci09CnPY8Ut4ZUsddWgXFIm6JP/view?usp=sharing

I cannot download the file at the moment, but have you set the Flow Behavior to Geometry or Inflow?

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
